# Simple Vertical Prev and Next buttons code on click moving up and down with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I had created a slider with this simple code

```
jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a:first").parent().parent().addClass("activeTab");
    jQuery(".accomdation_tab:first").addClass("active_tab_content");
    jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("activeTab");
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("activeTab"); 
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".accomdation_tab").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
```

With This Code I can display following content for each item on click.Now I need to create a Prev and Next button functionality too, When clicking to next it must scroll or move the next item and etc. i am trying with this code

```
jQuery('#single_article_next').click(function(){
        jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a").parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("activeTab"); 
        jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a:first").parent().parent().next().addClass("activeTab");
        jQuery(".accomdation_tab").siblings().removeClass("active_tab_content"); 
        jQuery('.accomdation_tab:first').next().addClass("active_tab_content"); 
    });
    jQuery('#single_article_prev').click(function(){
        jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a").parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("activeTab"); 
        jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a:first").parent().parent().prev().addClass("activeTab");
        jQuery(".accomdation_tab").siblings().removeClass("active_tab_content"); 
        jQuery('.accomdation_tab:first').prev().addClass("active_tab_content"); 
    });
```

But it is not what i need and didnt work properly.Help me to figure out.

Comment: My suggestion would be to wrap the article titles in `li` tags, it makes navigating them much simpler and will further the organization of your code.

Comment: Ok good suggestion thank you @DevlshOne and after wrapping what can I do to with buttons to work properly?

Comment: Why not just use a jquery plugin? There are masses of slider plugins so it seems that you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I used vertical bxslider but had problems with chnaging the right part content when navigating, you can see the example [here](http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/news-section/argentarius-to-exhibit-at-the-finance-malta-2015-conference/) @jcuenod

Comment: I had difficulties with giving active class to the next item

Comment: You also need to correct your `img` tags that are missing closes.  I'm working on a JSFiddle right now with your solution.

Comment: You mean Next and Prev images, right?It is html5.Thank you very much for wanting to help me @DevlshOne.I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, the `next` and `prev` images should be closed.. to make the code purely compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve `next`/`prev` functionality you have to take `activeTab` and to make active the next/previous one, like below.

Please notice that i replaced `.article_single_item` with `.activeTab` to take the active `a`.

```
var $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
```

The code below is for next/prev functionality. I extracted a part of common functionality in function `tabChange()`.

```
jQuery('#single_article_next').click(function(){
    var $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a"); 
    $activeTab.parent().parent().next().siblings().removeClass("activeTab"); 
    $activeTab.parent().parent().next().addClass("activeTab");

    $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
    tabChange($activeTab) 
});
jQuery('#single_article_prev').click(function(){
    var $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a"); 
    $activeTab.parent().parent().prev().siblings().removeClass("activeTab"); 
    $activeTab.parent().parent().prev().addClass("activeTab");

    $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
    tabChange($activeTab) 
});

function tabChange($activeTab) {
    var tab = $activeTab.attr("href");
    $(".accomdation_tab").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
}
```

**See the snippet** for the working example.

```js
jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a:first").parent().parent().addClass("activeTab");
jQuery(".accomdation_tab:first").addClass("active_tab_content");
jQuery(".article_single_item .article_singlepage_title a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().parent().addClass("activeTab");
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("activeTab");
  tabChange($(this))
});


jQuery('#single_article_next').click(function() {
  var $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
  $activeTab.parent().parent().next().siblings().removeClass("activeTab");
  $activeTab.parent().parent().next().addClass("activeTab");
  
  $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
  tabChange($activeTab)
});
jQuery('#single_article_prev').click(function() {
  var $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
  $activeTab.parent().parent().prev().siblings().removeClass("activeTab");
  $activeTab.parent().parent().prev().addClass("activeTab");

  $activeTab = jQuery(".activeTab .article_singlepage_title a");
  tabChange($activeTab)
});

function tabChange($activeTab) {

  var tab = $activeTab.attr("href");
  $(".accomdation_tab").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-7 column" style="float:none;margin:auto;">
  <div class="solutions_single_title">
    Solutions</div>
  <div class="single_sol_content">
    <p>We feel the best way to show you our solutions is to tell the stories of how our client successfully structured investment products using Exchange Traded Instruments (ETIs)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 single_solution_ipad_leftcol">
    <div class="article_scroll_list">
      <div class="other_art_title">Other Solutions</div>
      <div class="article_scroll_content">
        <div class="article_single_item activeTab">
          <div class="article_singlepage_title"><a href="#solution_1">Private Equity</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article_single_item">
          <div class="article_singlepage_title"><a href="#solution_2">The New Manager</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article_single_item">
          <div class="article_singlepage_title"><a href="#solution_3">SME Financing</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="article_single_item">
          <div class="article_singlepage_title"><a href="#solution_4">The UCITS Fund</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="article_list_border"></div>
      <span id="single_article_prev">
       <img src="http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/themes/argentarius/images/article_arrow_down.png" alt="article" class="arrow_down">
       <img src="http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/themes/argentarius/images/article_arrow_down_hover.png" alt="article" class="arrow_down_hover">
      </span>
      <span id="single_article_next">
       <img src="http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/themes/argentarius/images/article_arrow_up.png" alt="article" class="arrow_up">
       <img src="http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/wp-content/themes/argentarius/images/article_arrow_up_hover.png" alt="article" class="arrow_up_hover">
      </span> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 single_solution_ipad_rightcol">
    <div id="solution_1" class="accomdation_tab active_tab_content" style="">
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        Private Equity
      </div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        <p>A private equity manager based in a non EU jurisdiction consulted Argentarius to securitise a portfolio of investments in&nbsp;European SMEs with a listing on the Deutsche Börse and targeting professional investors in the EU.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        Own Issuer Vehicle</div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        <p>Argentarius created a branded Own Issuer Securitisation Cell Company for the manager to use as an EU base for investment opportunities.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="solution_2" class="accomdation_tab" style="display: none;">
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        The new manager
      </div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        A new start up long/short equity manager consulted Argentarius to securitise a trading account at a multi-asset prime broker and with an ETI listed on the Deutsche Börse for the initial funding to be received from professional investors. Costs were a
        prime concern here as the starting AUM was below 5 million euros. &nbsp;</div>
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        Fast and cost effective</div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        Our transparent cost structure meant that the new start up manager had control of their structuring costs from the start. Furthermore the ongoing management costs were clearly defined and the new manager could allocate the costs within the total management
        fee for the strategy.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="solution_3" class="accomdation_tab" style="display: none;">
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        SME Financing
      </div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        An asset manager securitised a portfolio of unlisted bonds arranged with European SMEs looking for new funding and listed it on the European Wholesale Securities Market as a target for professional investors and UCITS funds. The UCITS fund manager is
        therefore able to gain exposure to high yielding SME bonds that are managed by the fund manager through a power of attorney granted by the Special Investment Vehicle that forms part of the securitisation structure.</div>
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        SME Financing ETI</div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        A key requirement with this ETI was the cost of running the portfolio needed to be kept to a minimum and this was achieved by structuring the management of the SME Bonds through a Special Investment Vehicle (SIV) created as a 100% subsidiary of the Securitisation
        Cell Company. The selection of the bonds and the management of the repayments was directly handled by the UCITS fund manager under a power of attorney granted by the SIV.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="solution_4" class="accomdation_tab" style="display: none;">
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        The UCITS Fund seeking exposure to alternative investments
      </div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        A large UCITS fund manager securitised both an FX trading account and a Commodity Futures trading account with two separate brokers to achieve diversification for the fund. The ETI was listed on the European Wholesale Securities Market. The UCITS fund
        manager needed to be satisfied that the ETI met all the requirements of eligibility of assets, in addition to ensuring that no more than 10% of the AUM of the fund was invested within the ETI. The issuing Securitisation Cell Company had issued
        several hundred million Euros in securities and thus the UCITS fund manager was able to confirm that not more than 10% of the issuance of the Securitisation Cell Company had been purchased.</div>
      <div class="sigle_socenario_maintitle">
        The UCITS ETI</div>
      <div class="article_maincontent">
        The European Wholesale Securities Market is a joint venture between the Irish and Malta Stock Exchanges and offers an excellent venue for the listing of eligible UCITS assets that are backed by alternative investment portfolios.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I added it but it starts working fro the second click. see [here](http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/solutions/) @adricadar

Comment: can you help me with this, I love this variant @adricadar

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan it's my fault, i forgot to query again the new `$activeTab` see my code again.

Comment: Hey @adricadar what exactly I need to change, I added again your code but result is the same

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan you added the code from the snnipet? the code was wrong in the snippet, i corrected just now.

Comment: Yes added from the snippet

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap your articles like this**

```
<div class="article_scroll_content">
    <ul id="article_title_list">
        <li class="article_title">
            <div class="article_single_item activeTab">
                <div class="article_singlepage_title"> <a href="#solution_1">Private Equity</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="article_title">
            <div class="article_single_item">
                <div class="article_singlepage_title"> <a href="#solution_2">The New Manager</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="article_title">
            <div class="article_single_item">
                <div class="article_singlepage_title"> <a href="#solution_3">SME Financing</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="article_title">
            <div class="article_single_item">
                <div class="article_singlepage_title"> <a href="#solution_4">The UCITS Fund</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Then you can use some nicer code, like this**

```
$(function () {
    var $allTtitles = $('li.article_title');
    var titleCount = $('li.article_title').length;
    $('#title_count').html(titleCount);
    var newActiveTitleIdx = 0;
    var titleActiveIdx = 0;
    function titleListUp() {
        titleActiveIdx = $('li.article_title .active_title').index();
        $allTitles.removeClass('active_title');
        if (titleActiveIdx === 0) {
            newActiveTitleIdx = titleCount - 1;
        } else {
            newActiveTitleIdx--;
        }
        $('#art_idx').html(newActiveTitleIdx);
        $allTtitles.eq(newActiveTitleIdx).addClass('active_title');
    }

    function titleListDown() {
        titleActiveIdx = $('li.article_title .active_title').index();
        $allTitles.removeClass('active_title');
        if (titleActiveIdx == (titleCount - 1) ) {
            newActiveTitleIdx = 0;
        } else {
            newActiveTitleIdx++;
        }
        $('#art_idx').html(newActiveTitleIdx);
        $allTtitles.eq(newActiveTitleIdx).addClass('active_title');
    }
    $('#single_article_prev').on('click', function () {
        titleListUp();
    });
    $('#single_article_next').on('click', function () {
        titleListDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DevlshOne, let me try and see

Comment: I am getting an error number is not a function on this line   var titleCount = $('li.article_title').length();

Comment: Ooops... should be `.length` not `.length()`

Comment: Oh it didnt worked cause I had chnaged count variable to the post_id with <a href="#solution_<?php echo get_the_ID($post->ID) ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>

Comment: It didnt work @DevlshOne. see [here](http://argentarius.ipoint.com.mt/solutions/)

Comment: Yeah, I looked.. all the code I gave you was commented out. You're on your own.

Comment: what you mean @DevlshOne?